# How to get numbers from a string in Asp.net VB?

Tags: asp.net, arrays, vb.net, string

This is my string `"search=;pageid=62,67;categoryid=0;orderby=;showon=1"` I want to get 62 and 67 separately, how can I do this?

Comment: You can use regex: (\d+) with global flag, which will capture all numbers inside your string (including 1 at the end)

Comment: How rigid is the string format? If it's that format then regex may be best. If it's any freeform string that may contain numbers, stepping through a char at a time may work.

Comment: What have you researched and tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use [RegEx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). You can use this expression to get the optimized result:

```
(\d{2})
```

This RegEx finds all the numbers with 2 digits only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Split` and a `Lookup<TKey, TValue>`:

```
var yourString = " search=;pageid=62,67;categoryid=0;orderby=;showon=1";
var lookup = yourString.Trim().Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(t => t.Split('='))
    .ToLookup(arr => arr[0], arr => arr[1].Split(','));

string[] allPageIDs = lookup["pageid"].FirstOrDefault(); 
// allPageIDs can be null if the string didn't contain pageid
foreach (string id in allPageIDs)
    Console.WriteLine(id);
```

A lookup is similar to a dictionary but it if the input sequence contains the key multiple times no exception is raised but the value contains all results. Therefore `FirstOrDefault` above returns the first result which is a `string[]` with two values 62,67 in this case.

Comment: can i get 62 and 67 from "pageid=62,67"